# Unable to access internet after making ip static in beaglebone black

Tags: linux, debian, networking, ip, internet

I am trying to make my IP static in my Beaglebone black. For this I follow [this tutorial](http://derekmolloy.ie/set-ip-address-to-be-static-on-the-beaglebone-black/). After making changes according to tutorial, my /etc/network/interfaces file look like this:-

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.24.38
network 192.168.24.0
broadcast 192.168.24.255
netmask 255.255.252.0
gateway 192.168.25.10

# Example to keep MAC address between reboots
#hwaddress ether DE:AD:BE:EF:CA:FE

# The secondary network interface
#auto eth1
#iface eth1 inet dhcp

# WiFi Example
#auto wlan0
#iface wlan0 inet dhcp
#    wpa-ssid "essid"
#    wpa-psk  "password"

# Ethernet/RNDIS gadget (g_ether)
# ... or on host side, usbnet and random hwaddr
# Note on some boards, usb0 is automaticly setup with an init script
iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.7.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.7.0
    gateway 192.168.7.1
```

After reboot my Beaglebone black, I can see my IP is static ip by using command `ifconfig`. here is the output of command `ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:39:72:3b:da:e8  
          inet addr:192.168.24.38  Bcast:192.168.24.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d239:72ff:fe3b:dae8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3352 errors:0 dropped:63 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:77 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:329055 (321.3 KiB)  TX bytes:10701 (10.4 KiB)
          Interrupt:40 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:79 (79.0 B)  TX bytes:79 (79.0 B)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 66:b8:b3:7a:c3:19  
          inet addr:192.168.7.2  Bcast:192.168.7.3  Mask:255.255.255.252
          inet6 addr: fe80::64b8:b3ff:fe7a:c319/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:88 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:76 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:13642 (13.3 KiB)  TX bytes:17130 (16.7 KiB)
```

But now I am unable to access the Internet. So. please tell me where is the mistake in my settings. Thanks

As suggested , output of command `ip route` is:-

```
  default via 192.168.25.10 dev eth0 
    192.168.7.0/30 dev usb0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.7.2 
    192.168.24.0/22 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.24.38
```

And output of command `ping -c1 google.com` is

ping: unknown host google.com

output of command  `netstat -nr`

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U         0 0          0 usb0
```

Comment: Please add to the post. Home, ISP or corporate network? What is the output of `ip route` and `ping -c1 google.com`. If you did not mix up the gateway, which is rather unusual at 10, all seems ok in /etc/networks/interfaces.

Comment: Switch it back to DHCP, and then add the output of `ifconfig` (and @RuiFRibeiro 's commands)

Comment: I suspect you mixed up the gateway...it seems more logical it to be `192.168.25.1`

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro , please check the output of commands you ask, Same configurations works on raspberry pi. And these are the only configurations which is provided to me by  company. These sam configuration works on my UBUNTU system as well. So, I think gateway is fine

Comment: The commands are pretty basic do not worry.; they are working fine in my raspberry clone here too. `ip route` can also be done as `netstat -nr`.

Comment: @ EightBitTony :- DHCP won't work as these are the only configuration available to me

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro :- should I post output of netstst -nr?

Comment: I asked you the netstat and ping.I suspect what is happening is that you do not have `/etc/resolv.conf` properly filled in, and thus no DNS. DHCP usually fills it too.

Comment: output of netstat -nr  is
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U         0 0          0 usb0

and ping have same output

Comment: I have add output of netstat -nr in my question

Comment: i have add output in my question , please refer to last few lines in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output ping and netstat command confirms that all is fine with routing. However DHCP also gives DNS/resolver setup data. The DNS resolution is failing.

Please edit your /etc/resolv.conf and fill it in as:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

ping google.com should be working then.

Later on talk with your company, and ask them the internal domain (yourdomain.xx) and the IP of their nameserver (localnameserver)

and change it to:

```
search yourdomain.xx
nameserver localnameserver
```